# Logging the PID in log4j2 without using thread context

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I need to include the PID in my log4js logs. I see many examples which use the thread context. However, these need to be set on each individual thread created. I am constrained against doing this.

I need a solution that, either, does not use the thread context, or, can set the PID on all thread contexts, for any thread that may be created, from any arbitrary class.

Comment: We've added a feature request for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1884

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please create a feature request on the Log4j2 [issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira) to make this a built-in feature.

For now, you can create a custom plugin. See code below. This will allow you to specify `%pid` in the [pattern layout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout) (similar to `%m` for the message).

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;

@Plugin(name = "ProcessIdPatternConverter", category = "Converter")
@ConverterKeys({ "pid", "processId" })
public final class ProcessIdPatternConverter extends LogEventPatternConverter {
    private final String pid;

    private ProcessIdPatternConverter(String[] options) {
        super("Process ID", "pid");
        String temp = options.length > 0 ? options[0] : "???";
        try {
            // likely works on most platforms
            temp = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName().split("@")[0];
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            try {
                // try a Linux-specific way
                temp = new File("/proc/self").getCanonicalFile().getName();
            } catch (final IOException ignoredUseDefault) {}
        }
        pid = temp;
    }

    /**
     * Obtains an instance of ProcessIdPatternConverter.
     *
     * @param options users may specify a default like {@code %pid{NOPID} }
     * @return instance of ProcessIdPatternConverter.
     */
    public static ProcessIdPatternConverter newInstance(final String[] options) {
        return new ProcessIdPatternConverter(options);
    }

    @Override
    public void format(final LogEvent event, final StringBuilder toAppendTo) {
        toAppendTo.append(pid);
    }
}
```

See the [manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html) for more details on how Log4j2 plugins work.

One way to let Log4j2 recognize your plugin is by specifying the package name of the plugin class in the `packages` attribute of the configuration:

```
<Configuration status="trace" 
     packages="com.myorg.mypluginpackage">
```

(Trace switches on Log4j2 internal debugging to help with troubleshooting.)

Comment: Yes, but would you please edit the answer to include information about adding the package of the new class to the log4j2.xml configuration?