# Log4j2 custom layout Patterns

Tags: java, log4j2

Hi I am migrating from log4j to log4j2.

In my code I found some custom patterns class are used. I am not sure how to implement the same in log4j2. 
Can anybody help me on this?

Here is the code I'm using

```
public class MyPatternLayout extends PatternLayout
{
    protected PatternParser createPatternParser(String pattern)
    {
        return new MyPatternParser(pattern);
    }
}

public class MyPatternParser extends PatternParser
{
    private static class MyPatternConverter extends PatternConverter
    {

        int type = 0;

        public String convert(LoggingEvent event)
        {
            String converted = "";
            try
            {
                switch (type)
                {
                    case 33: // 'I' - Requiest Unique ID
                        UniqueId id = (UniqueId) ActParam.getParameter(LoggerParams.activityId);
                        if (id == null)
                        {
                            id = new UniqueId();
                            ActParam.setParameter(LoggerParams.activityId, id);
                        }
                        converted = id.getId();
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogLog.error("Error processing activityId.", ex);
            }
            return converted;
        }

        MyPatternConverter(FormattingInfo formattingInfo, int type)
        {
            super(formattingInfo);
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    public MyPatternParser(String pattern)
    {
        super(pattern);

    }

    protected void finalizeConverter(char c)
    {
        PatternConverter pc = null;
        switch (c)
        {
            case 33: 
            case 53: 
                pc = new MyPatternConverter(formattingInfo, c);
                currentLiteral.setLength(0);

                addConverter(pc);
                break;
            default:
                super.finalizeConverter(c);
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance.

After the suggestions to change to @plugins, below is my code.

```
@Plugin(name = "MyPatternLayout", category = "Converter")
@ConverterKeys(
{
        "zs"
})
public class MyPatternLayout extends LogEventPatternConverter
{
    protected MyPatternLayout(String name, String style)
    {
        super(name, style);
    }

    public static MyPatternLayout newInstance(String[] options)
    {
        return new MyPatternLayout("zs", Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder toAppendTo)
    {

        toAppendTo.append(getTransactionId());
    }
    protected String getTransactionId()
    {

        String converted = "";
        try
        {
             UniqueId id = (UniqueId) ThreadParameter.getParameter(LoggerThreadParameters.activityId);
            if (id == null)
            {
                id = new UniqueId();
                ThreadParameter.setParameter(LoggerThreadParameters.activityId, id);
            }
            converted = id.getId();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            StatusLogger.getLogger().error("Error processing activityId.", ex);
        }
        return converted;
    }

}
```

and the log4j2.xml is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="trace" packages="com.metavante.efd.cms.log.log4j.EFDPatternLayout">
       <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
     <PatternLayout pattern="%p|%d{ISO8601}|%c|%m|%zs%n"/>

    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <loggers>
     <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="all" />
     <root level="all">
            <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" level="TRACE" />
      </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

and the output in the log is like blow.

```
2017-07-06 10:55:32,137 main DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\eclipse\workspace\test\test.ear\test.war\WEB-INF\xml\log4j2.xml]
2017-07-06 10:55:32,152 main DEBUG Installed script engines
2017-07-06 10:55:32,652 main DEBUG Oracle Nashorn Version: 1.8.0_121, Language: ECMAScript, Threading: Not Thread Safe, Compile: true, Names: {nashorn, Nashorn, js, JS, JavaScript, javascript, ECMAScript, ecmascript}
2017-07-06 10:55:32,659 main DEBUG Took 0.005574 seconds to load 0 plugins from package com.log4j.MyPatternLayout
2017-07-06 10:55:32,659 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Core' found 112 plugins
2017-07-06 10:55:32,659 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Level' found 0 plugins
2017-07-06 10:55:32,665 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Lookup' found 13 plugins
2017-07-06 10:55:32,668 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=layout, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout].
2017-07-06 10:55:32,686 main TRACE TypeConverterRegistry initializing.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,687 main DEBUG PluginManager 'TypeConverter' found 26 plugins
2017-07-06 10:55:32,708 main DEBUG PatternLayout$Builder(pattern="%p|%d{ISO8601}|%c|%m|%zs%n", PatternSelector=null, Configuration(C:\eclipse\workspace\test\test.ear\test.war\WEB-INF\xml\log4j2.xml), Replace=null, charset="null", alwaysWriteExceptions="null", disableAnsi="null", noConsoleNoAnsi="null", header="null", footer="null")
2017-07-06 10:55:32,709 main DEBUG PluginManager 'Converter' found 41 plugins
2017-07-06 10:55:32,733 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [zs]
2017-07-06 10:55:32,734 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [zs] starting at position 24 in conversion pattern.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,734 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender].
2017-07-06 10:55:32,748 main DEBUG ConsoleAppender$Builder(target="SYSTEM_OUT", follow="null", direct="null", bufferedIo="null", bufferSize="null", immediateFlush="null", ignoreExceptions="null", PatternLayout(%p|%d{ISO8601}|%c|%m|%zs%n), name="STDOUT", Configuration(C:\eclipse\workspace\test\test.ear\test.war\WEB-INF\xml\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-07-06 10:55:32,758 main DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream
2017-07-06 10:55:32,758 main DEBUG Starting OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false
2017-07-06 10:55:32,759 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appenders, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppendersPlugin].
2017-07-06 10:55:32,761 main DEBUG createAppenders(={STDOUT})
2017-07-06 10:55:32,762 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=logger, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig].
2017-07-06 10:55:32,771 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="true", level="ALL", name="org.apache.log4j.xml", includeLocation="null", ={}, ={}, Configuration(C:\eclipse\workspace\test\test.ear\test.war\WEB-INF\xml\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-07-06 10:55:32,776 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=appender-ref, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef].
2017-07-06 10:55:32,777 main DEBUG createAppenderRef(ref="STDOUT", level="TRACE", Filter=null)
2017-07-06 10:55:32,777 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger].
2017-07-06 10:55:32,778 main DEBUG createLogger(additivity="null", level="ALL", includeLocation="null", ={STDOUT}, ={}, Configuration(C:\eclipse\workspace\test\test.ear\test.war\WEB-INF\xml\log4j2.xml), Filter=null)
2017-07-06 10:55:32,779 main DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin].
2017-07-06 10:55:32,781 main DEBUG createLoggers(={org.apache.log4j.xml, root})
2017-07-06 10:55:32,783 main DEBUG Configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\eclipse\workspace\test\test.ear\test.war\WEB-INF\xml\log4j2.xml] initialized
2017-07-06 10:55:32,783 main DEBUG Starting configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\eclipse\workspace\test\test.ear\test.war\WEB-INF\xml\log4j2.xml]
2017-07-06 10:55:32,784 main DEBUG Started configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\eclipse\workspace\test\test.ear\test.war\WEB-INF\xml\log4j2.xml] OK.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,784 main TRACE Stopping org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@51931956...
2017-07-06 10:55:32,785 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notified 1 ReliabilityStrategies that config will be stopped.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,785 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping root LoggerConfig.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,785 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration notifying ReliabilityStrategies that appenders will be stopped.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,786 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopping remaining Appenders.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,786 main DEBUG Shutting down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1
2017-07-06 10:55:32,786 main DEBUG Shut down OutputStreamManager SYSTEM_OUT.false.false-1, all resources released: true
2017-07-06 10:55:32,786 main DEBUG Appender DefaultConsole-1 stopped with status true
2017-07-06 10:55:32,787 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration stopped 1 remaining Appenders.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,787 main TRACE DefaultConfiguration cleaning Appenders from 1 LoggerConfigs.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,787 main DEBUG Stopped org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration@51931956 OK
2017-07-06 10:55:32,790 main TRACE Reregistering MBeans after reconfigure. Selector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector@71c27ee8
2017-07-06 10:55:32,790 main TRACE Reregistering context (1/1): '18b4aac2' org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3e7dd664
2017-07-06 10:55:32,791 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2'
2017-07-06 10:55:32,791 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger'
2017-07-06 10:55:32,792 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector'
2017-07-06 10:55:32,792 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*'
2017-07-06 10:55:32,793 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=*'
2017-07-06 10:55:32,793 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncAppenders,name=*'
2017-07-06 10:55:32,794 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=AsyncLoggerRingBuffer'
2017-07-06 10:55:32,794 main TRACE Unregistering but no MBeans found matching 'org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=*,subtype=RingBuffer'
2017-07-06 10:55:32,799 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2
2017-07-06 10:55:32,802 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=StatusLogger
2017-07-06 10:55:32,805 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=ContextSelector
2017-07-06 10:55:32,807 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=
2017-07-06 10:55:32,808 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Loggers,name=org.apache.log4j.xml
2017-07-06 10:55:32,812 main DEBUG Registering MBean org.apache.logging.log4j2:type=18b4aac2,component=Appenders,name=STDOUT
2017-07-06 10:55:32,818 main TRACE Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,819 main TRACE Using DummyNanoClock for nanosecond timestamps.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,819 main DEBUG Reconfiguration complete for context[name=18b4aac2] at URI C:\eclipse\workspace\test\test.ear\test.war\WEB-INF\xml\log4j2.xml (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3e7dd664) with optional ClassLoader: null
2017-07-06 10:55:32,820 main DEBUG Shutdown hook enabled. Registering a new one.
2017-07-06 10:55:32,822 main DEBUG LoggerContext[name=18b4aac2, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@3e7dd664] started OK.
DEBUG|2017-07-06T10:55:32,836|Default.com.JBossStartupClass|deleting directory: C:\eclipse\workspace\test\test.ear\test.war\WEB-INF\templates|%zs
2017-07-06 10:55:32,843 main DEBUG AsyncLogger.ThreadNameStrategy=CACHED
2017-07-06 10:55:32,843 main TRACE Using default SystemClock for timestamps.
```

and I think somehow it is not finding the plugin. Please help me.
Note: I am working with JBoss EAP 7.

and when I use log4j2.proeprties file instead of logj2.xml it is giving different error in the log.

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename =logs
appenders =console
appender.console.type =Console
appender.console.name =STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type =com.log4j.MyPatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern =%p|%d{ISO8601}|%c|%m|%zs%n

rootLogger.level =debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs =stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref =STDOUT
```

and below is the log in the console when I use .proeprties file.

```
2017-07-06 11:02:48,374 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin type for com.metavante.efd.cms.log.log4j.EFDPatternLayout
2017-07-06 11:02:48,433 main ERROR Unable to locate plugin for com.metavante.efd.cms.log.log4j.EFDPatternLayout
2017-07-06 11:02:48,455 main ERROR Unable to inject fields into builder class for plugin type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender, element Console. java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.findNamedNode(PluginElementVisitor.java:103)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.visitors.PluginElementVisitor.visit(PluginElementVisitor.java:87)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.injectFields(PluginBuilder.java:179)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:121)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:952)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:892)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:884)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:508)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:232)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:174)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:618)
    at com.metavante.efd.util.logging.logStore.types.Log4jLogStore.<init>(Log4jLogStore.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.metavante.efd.util.logging.LoggerProperties.getLogStore(LoggerProperties.java:148)
    at com.metavante.efd.util.logging.Logger.getLogStoreInstance(Logger.java:97)
    at com.metavante.efd.util.logging.Logger.debug(Logger.java:155)
    at com.fis.customAgent.local.JBoss_Startup_Agent.cleanDirectories(JBoss_Startup_Agent.java:220)
    at com.fis.customAgent.local.JBoss_Startup_Agent.premain(JBoss_Startup_Agent.java:182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source)

2017-07-06 11:02:48,461 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender for element Console. java.lang.IllegalStateException: No factory method found for class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.ConsoleAppender
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.findFactoryMethod(PluginBuilder.java:224)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:130)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:952)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:892)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:884)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:508)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:232)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:244)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:545)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:617)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:634)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:229)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:242)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:174)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:618)
    at com.metavante.efd.util.logging.logStore.types.Log4jLogStore.<init>(Log4jLogStore.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.metavante.efd.util.logging.LoggerProperties.getLogStore(LoggerProperties.java:148)
    at com.metavante.efd.util.logging.Logger.getLogStoreInstance(Logger.java:97)
    at com.metavante.efd.util.logging.Logger.debug(Logger.java:155)
    at com.fis.customAgent.local.JBoss_Startup_Agent.cleanDirectories(JBoss_Startup_Agent.java:220)
    at com.fis.customAgent.local.JBoss_Startup_Agent.premain(JBoss_Startup_Agent.java:182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(Unknown Source)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(Unknown Source)

2017-07-06 11:02:48,463 main ERROR Null object returned for Console in Appenders.
2017-07-06 11:02:48,464 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "STDOUT" for logger config "root"
```

Please help me in this. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The best place to start is the [Log4j2 source code](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/index.html). Pattern converters live in the  `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern` package. A nice and simple standalone converter is [UuidPatternConverter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/UuidPatternConverter.html).

See  also this answer showing a [custom pid pattern converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43427618/1446916).

Key points:

1. No need to extend PatternLayout or PatternParser
2. Instead, extend [LogEventPatternConverter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/LogEventPatternConverter.html)
3. Log4j2 uses a plugin mechanism to extend its functionality. The built-in PatternConverters are also plugins.
4. See the Log4j2 [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#PatternConverters) on custom PatternConverter plugin annotations

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried using plugin and I wrote my logic inside that and when I run my application that plugin class is not calling at all.(I put a break point in there). I am referring this is log4j2.xml file like                                   <configuration xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
       status="trace" packages="com.my.log4j.MyPatternLayout">

Comment: That configuration snippet looks okay. You don't need the xmlns attribute, not sure if it does any harm. Would you mind posting the full configuration and the output of the Log4j2 internal status logging?

Comment: Hi Popma,Modified the question. Please take a look.

Comment: Looks like %prg is interpreted as %p (log level is DEBUG), followed by "rg". Try a different key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. :) yes you are correct. but when I change from prg to zs it is giving below log. DEBUG|2017-07-123 8:43:33,844|Default.com.JBossStartupClass|Copying templates...|%zs. My doubt is that, is this plugin recognizing or not? Do you have any other suggestions. please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, what about the `packages` attribute, it looks like it has a space at the end, that should not be there. Also, with `<configuration status="trace"` you should see a lot of internal Log4j2 debug statements on the console that may give insight into what is going wrong. Are you seeing this internal Log4j2 logging?

Comment: I see some logs in the console. getting some errors 2017-07-06 09:46:40,155 main ERROR Unrecognized format specifier [zs]
2017-07-06 09:46:40,156 main ERROR Unrecognized conversion specifier [zs] starting at position 24 in conversion pattern.2017-07-06 09:46:40,177 main DEBUG Jansi is not installed, cannot find org.fusesource.jansi.WindowsAnsiOutputStream

Comment: Ok. Your plugin is not being recognized for some reason. Please update the question with the exact latest code & configuration, and the Log4j2 debug console output.

Comment: Hi Popma, I updated the question with latest code. Thank you.

Comment: The `packages` configuration attribute should only have the package name, not the full class name. Also, is it possible you have multiple versions of Log4j2 on the classpath? I've seen that error before (built-in plugins failing) with multiple versions of Log4j2 on the classpath.

Comment: Oh I misread; the last exception only happens with the properties configuration. I'm not that familiar with the properties configuration syntax, it looks okay to me except there's no `packages` property defined pointing to your custom plugin package and the layout type should be the built-in `PatternLayout`, not `com.log4j.MyPatternLayout`.